# Script to autofill google doc from google form using checkboxes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-forms

I have the following issue.  I am trying to create a script that will autofill a template google document using the submission of a google form.  I am able to get the script to work for questions that are input with text but am struggling on getting the data from questions in the form that are checkboxes (or multiple choice) to work and fill the google document.  Any assistance would be great.  For example the variable identified as "offense" is from a question with checkboxes that has about 30 different options, I would like each option that is checked on the form to replace text within my google doc.  Thanks.

```
 function autoFillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
  //e.values is an array of form values
  var timestamp = e.values[4];
  var studentName = e.values[3];
  var oe = e.values[16];
  var gradelevel = e.values[14];
  var program = e.values[15];
  var offense = e.values[6];
  var action = e.values[18];
  var serve = e.values[31];
  var makeUp = e.values[32];
  var comments = e.values[29];
  
  
  //file is the template file, and you get it by ID
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1nPWC0IKc1zUJXYxbGahJsSW4uNWwhxnLM8shcD8kEE4'); 
  
  //We can make a copy of the template, name it, and optionally tell it what folder to live in
  //file.makeCopy will return a Google Drive file object
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1FlpHRKqYrEHttA-3ozU3oUVJlgiqqa-F')
  var copy = file.makeCopy(studentName + ', ' + timestamp, folder); 
  
  //Once we've got the new file created, we need to open it as a document by using its ID
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId()); 
  
  //Since everything we need to change is in the body, we need to get that
  var body = doc.getBody(); 
  
  //Then we call all of our replaceText methods
  body.replaceText('<<Student Name>>', studentName); 
  body.replaceText('<<Incident Date>>', timestamp);  
  body.replaceText('<<Student Grade>>', gradelevel); 
  body.replaceText('<<Open enrolled?>>', oe);
  body.replaceText('<<IEP/504?>>', program);
  body.replaceText('<<Reason for Referral (Handbook)>>', offense);
  body.replaceText('<<Administrative Action>>', action);
  body.replaceText('<<Date(s) to be Served>>', serve);
  body.replaceText('<<Make up Date(s)>>', makeUp);
  body.replaceText('<<Comments>>', comments);

  //Lastly we save and close the document to persist our changes
  doc.saveAndClose(); 
}
```

Comment: What are you currently getting with the answers with checkboxes? Are they empty or show something else?

Comment: It is just leaving the identifiers for replacement, for example  <<Date(s) to be Served>> is left as <<Date(s) to be Served>> instead of the dates that were checked in the form.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the labels assigned to the checkboxes to determine if they have been checked.  Same for multiple coice.

You can't use ListItems because you can't set the glyph to a check box so I simply insert text with a checkbox character.

I created a form

[image]
[image]

I then created an onFormSubmit(e) installed trigger in the spreadsheet to get the form response and put it in the Doc.  Here I've simply used an active doc to perform my tests.  You will need to adjust the script to handle your template doc.

```
function onFormSubmit() {
   //  test data
let e = {"authMode":"FULL","namedValues":{"Timestamp":["8/16/2022 14:40:26"],"Student Grade":["Junior"],"Reason for Referrel":["Bad grades, Disruptive in class, Other"],"Student Name":["Joe Smith"],"Open Enrollment":["Yes"]},"range":{"columnEnd":5,"columnStart":1,"rowEnd":2,"rowStart":2},"source":{},"triggerUid":"12151926","values":["8/16/2022 14:40:26","Joe Smith","Junior","Yes","Bad grades, Disruptive in class, Other"]};
  
  try {
    let doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    let body = doc.getBody();

    let referrels = ["Bad grades","Unexcused absence","Disruptive in class","Fighting","Other"];

    body.replaceText("<<Student Name>>",e.namedValues["Student Name"]);
    body.replaceText("<<Student Grade>>",e.namedValues["Student Grade"]);
    body.replaceText("<<Open Enrollment>>",e.namedValues["Open Enrollment"]);
    // Notice the regex expression below because findText doesn't seem to handle parenthesis well
    let text = body.findText("<<Reason for Referral.*>>");
    body.replaceText("<<Reason for Referral.*>>","");
    if( text ) {
      let index = body.getChildIndex(text.getElement().getParent())+1;
      referrels.forEach( item => {
          let checked = e.namedValues["Reason for Referrel"][0].indexOf(item);
          if( checked >= 0 ) {
            let listItem = body.insertListItem(index,item);
            index = body.getChildIndex(listItem)+1;
          }
        }
      );
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your time on this and I apologize for my incompetence, but how then do I integrate this into my current script?

Comment: First I would ask you to Logger.log the e.value to make sure it’s the similar to what I have shown.  Because your script seems to have a different e.value style.

Comment: It's unclear how you want to handle the checkboxes since multiple checkboxes can be checked.

Comment: As @TheWizEd mentioned, Checkbox returns an array. Since multiple options can be selected. Maybe you can do a for loop for the values selected in the array?

Comment: I've updated my script to handle multiple check boxes.

Comment: I appreciate all of the effort you have put into this @TheWizEd, I like what you have done and may be able to adjust to make what I am looking for.  To clarify, basically what is happening in my form is I have a list of infractions from a code of misconduct that needs to be inserted into documentation that is sent home with students, in many instances they have multiple offenses (and/or multiple consequences) and in the document they need to be comma separated.  Here is a copy of the document that I am working on, you can see in the highlighted areas where I would want

Comment: the checkboxes text to be listed.  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nW-JhjAHKSsNkMSz3QGrXTCFqVHU1vmIlyMIFmcx4iQ/edit

Comment: I've updated my script to provide a ListItem instead of checkboxes.